# How to catch non-browser traffic on Eclipse Android Emulator through Fiddler

Tags: android, eclipse, networking, fiddler

I want to look at trafiic on Android Emulator in Eclipse through Fiddler.
Capturing on all processes is still missing non-browser trafiic. My Emulator Android have proxy setted to my local machine but i see ony Browser traffic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2/8947876#8947876

Wireshark and WebScarab good alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You may have gone through these same steps, but here is what I did to get it to work.  I pieced together info from different sites including Fiddler2.com:

- In Fiddler, click Tools / Fiddler Options / Connections and ensure that the box Allow remote computers to connect is checked. (Restart Fiddler if this box wasn't already checked .)
- Then Note the IP Address of the Fiddler PC; you can see this by hovering over the icon in Fiddler's toolbar: (it's just the IP of your pc):
  [image]
- Then on the emulator go to Setting->Wireless&Networks->Mobile Networks -> AccessPointNames.  I used the existing APN (T-Mobile US) and just changed the Proxy and Port.
- Proxy is just the IP from previous step (I did not need to enter http://)
- Port is 8888
- Restart the emulator and you should see your app traffic in Fiddler.